# Aligning multiple tikz and algorithms with subfigure

Tags: graphics, subcaption

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \Function{CCCCCCCCCCCC}{}
                \State $AAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
                \State $BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$
                \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
\State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
                \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[c]{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=1]
                % Leiste unten
                \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                \draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,.-.1);
                \draw (.2,.05) -- (.2,-.05);
                \draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,-.05);
                \draw (.6,.05) -- (.6,-.05);
                \draw (.8,.05) -- (.8,-.05);
                \draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
                % Knoten unten
                
                \newcommand\AONE{.5*0}
                \newcommand\ATWO{.5*1}
                \newcommand\ATHREE{.5*2}
                
                \newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
                % U
                \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.3,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=green!30] (0.5,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.5,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATHREE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                
                
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{CCCCCCCCCCCC}{}
            \State $AAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
            \State $BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=1]
            % Leiste unten
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
            \draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,.-.1);
            \draw (.2,.05) -- (.2,-.05);
            \draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,-.05);
            \draw (.6,.05) -- (.6,-.05);
            \draw (.8,.05) -- (.8,-.05);
            \draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
            % Knoten unten
            
            \newcommand\AONE{.5*0}
            \newcommand\ATWO{.5*1}
            \newcommand\ATHREE{.5*2}
            
            \newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
            % U
            \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.3,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=green!30] (0.5,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.5,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATHREE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            
            
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{AAAA}
        \label{fig:AA-AA}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can i fix this? I want that both algorithms be top aligned and each picture be centered vertically with respect to the corresponding algorithm on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tikzpictures to be aligned to the centers of the algorithms, you must place the baselines for both at the center (which is the default for subfigure).  Algorithmic expands to fill the available space, so `\centering` does nothing.  Tikzpictures can be centered, but I have the suspicion you wanted them left justified.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \Function{CCCCCCCCCCCC}{}
                \State $AAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
                \State $BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$
                \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
                \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{subfigure}\hfil
        \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
          \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=1]
                % Leiste unten
                \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
                \draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,.-.1);
                \draw (.2,.05) -- (.2,-.05);
                \draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,-.05);
                \draw (.6,.05) -- (.6,-.05);
                \draw (.8,.05) -- (.8,-.05);
                \draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
                % Knoten unten
                
                \newcommand\AONE{.5*0}
                \newcommand\ATWO{.5*1}
                \newcommand\ATHREE{.5*2}
                
                \newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
                % U
                \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.3,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=green!30] (0.5,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.5,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATHREE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
                
                
            \end{tikzpicture}  
        \end{subfigure}
        \par\vskip\floatsep
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{CCCCCCCCCCCC}{}
            \State $AAAAAAAAAAAAAA$
            \State $BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \State $XXXXXXXXXXXXX$
            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=4,yscale=1]
            % Leiste unten
            \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
            \draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,.-.1);
            \draw (.2,.05) -- (.2,-.05);
            \draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,-.05);
            \draw (.6,.05) -- (.6,-.05);
            \draw (.8,.05) -- (.8,-.05);
            \draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
            % Knoten unten
            
            \newcommand\AONE{.5*0}
            \newcommand\ATWO{.5*1}
            \newcommand\ATHREE{.5*2}
            
            \newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
            % U
            \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.3,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=green!30] (0.5,0.2+\ATWO) rectangle ++(0.5,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            \draw[fill=blue!30] (0.3,0.2+\ATHREE) rectangle ++(0.2,\BLOCKHEIGHT);
            
            
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{AAAA}
        \label{fig:AA-AA}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: what have you changed? i dont understand what is going on?

Comment: so i need to remove [t]

Comment: it is looking perfect

Comment: Basically yes.  All you need to do is remove the [t] from subfigure.  I did add a few tweak, like `\vskip\floatsep` between the two rows.